# Validate a GET string but still use special characters?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

One of my GET variables allows for all the characters that can mess up a URL by urlencoding them. Trouble is that means tags can be passed to the script and displayed in the html, not good! Especially since it gets used to run a SELECT on a mysql db.

So what I'm using at the moment is a hashed together preg_replace that strips out any tags (below)

```
$getstring = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+)([^>]*>)/e","", $getstring);
```

Is this sufficient or is there a gapping big hole I've missed?

Comment: Do you want to eliminate the characters or escape them?

Comment: What about `strip_tags`? http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: strip_tags!!! forgot about that one, how embarassing :) good call!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) will allow special characters to be displayed. HTML tags will be shown as normal text (i.e. escaped) so if anyone has too much time, you can see what they've tried. If you want to filter some tags after that, use the previous attempts to guide you.

If you want to allow some formatting, use [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip_tags) with a whitelist to allow some basic tags. Alternatively, a markup language such as [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)(used here) or [ReMarkable](http://camendesign.com/remarkable) might be useful, depending on the user's technical level.

It sounds as if you're vulnerable to SQL Injection, too. You should be using parametrised queries wherever possible, using mysqli (the question has the mysql-query tag) or PDO. [`PDO::prepare()`](http://php.net/pdo.prepare) should get you up to speed on this.

Comment: If i understand correctly, he wants to keep tags and display them after so strip_tags doesn't cut it...as for the prepare(), good point!

Comment: @Catalin: Taylor's regex replaces tags with the empty string; I don't see how that's conducive to keeping them.

Comment: true, wasn't paying attention, sry

Comment: php decodes a get string automatically. Thanks for the mysqli tip, been meaning to look more in to that. And yes, I want to keep special characters like > & $ < etc but remove the risk of html tag insertion by some idiot with too much time!

Comment: @Taylor: Ah, I see now. Well, if you use htmlspecialchars on its own, any tags would be escaped, so special chars would be kept and <tags> would be *shown*

Answer (score 1):

Try using: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php